# Atom menu bar labels are invisible

Tags: atom-editor

When using Atom (v.1.33.0) the menu bar labels aren't shown. They are invisible but the open by mouse-over...  (see screenshot, sorry for the low resolution)
[image]

The doesn't appear with other themes either.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE:**
 Issue is opened already on github: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/18535
Changing Ubuntu Theme "helps". Seems to be an issue caused by the combination of Atom and Ubuntu Themes...

Comment: Same here, I think it also started with the 1.33 update.

Comment: Issue is opened already on github: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/18535